# Why classes in "client" package work fine on server?

Tags: java, gwt

I don't understand why classes (beans) which are located inside "clent" package work fine on server side? In GWT module "client" package I set as  `<source path='client'/>`

I always think that I need to locate my classes into Shared package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a convention really. If the class is just a bean and can be used on the server too, then sure, put it in `shared`.

Some beans may not actually be used on the server in some cases however, so putting them in a `shared` directory may be a premature optimization.

Comment: `so putting them in a shared` typo? You mean `client`?

Comment: No, it is not typo. The 'shared' folder is useful to keep classes that are used both at the client side as well as the server side.

Comment: It wasn't a typo, putting classes that are not actually shared in the shared directory may hurt you, for example if you decided to make them client-side-only classes you'd have to move them back. Either way it's just a convention, and there is no naming requirement for the client/server/shared directories.

Comment: @JasonHall yes, I understand it. I confused why when we put class inside `client` package we can use this class on server-side too as well?

Comment: @MyTitle You'll need to give us more details about your build setup to know the answer to that. Does your server package have a dependency on the client package? GWT doesn't do anything at all to manage server dependencies and keep client code from being available on the server..

Comment: `Does your server package have a dependency on the client package?` yes, I use POJO classes from `client` package inside servlets. More details? ok. 
1. In gwt-module I have only  `<source path='client'/> <source path='shared'/>`
2. For compiling I use gwt-maven-plugin

Comment: You may want to put those shared POJOs into the `shared` package, so that the `server` package doesn't pick up all of the stuff in `client`

Comment: i.e. in my case compiler try to compile whole  `client` package as `.java` classes?